# Car racing problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A speedway turn, with radius of curvature $R$, is banked at an angle $\theta$ above the horizontal. If there is a coefficient of static friction, $\mu_{s}$ between the tires and the track, what are the maximum and minimum speeds at which turn can be taken?

My solution:
Since coefficient of kinetic friction, $\mu_{k}$ $\leq$ $\mu_{s}$ ,  I have shown that maximum speed  $$ v = \sqrt {\frac{R\, g \sin\theta+ \mu_{s}\cos\theta} {\cos\theta-\mu_{s} \sin\theta}}$$, where $g$ = gravitational constant

Any advice on finding the minimum speed?

Thank you!

Comment: In the direction perpendicular to motion there is no slipping of the tires so the kinetic friction is irrelevent. Only static fricion is important.

Comment: This question clearly shows research. The specific physics concept is about banking of roads, where a maximum safe velocity while taking the turn is usually determined, but where it is unusual to determine a minimum velocity since in most real cases, the minimum velocity is 0.

Comment: Regarding friction of the tires, the lateral friction may differ a bit
from the logitudinal friction because the use, the structure and the
surface of tires is not isotropic. I also doubt that the effect of
"static" lateral friction is the same when the car is still and when
it is moving, because of tire deformation which probably allows for
some slippage, without leaving the static friction domain. I think
this would also be speed dependent. All this is just my guess, but it
seems confirmed on the web: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_angle

Comment: Too bad this question is closed. It raises an interesting issue regarding lateral friction of a rolling body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine $\theta$ to be quite large, about 80$^\circ$. Any normal car would fall down(rather slip down against the friction force from tires.) But if the speed of the car is very high, the centrifugal force would prevent it from slipping(imagine a horizontal roller coaster loop-the-loop).

The frictional force would have to act *up the incline* in this case to counter a component of the weight down the incline.

Also, consider static friction, not kinetic. The friction is the *sideways dragging of the tires* and not related to their kinetic/rolling motion.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Hence,if $\theta$ tends to $90$ $^\circ$., then the centripetal force responsible for keeping the car in track $\approx$ $N$, where $N$ is the normal force?

Comment: Yes, but $\mu_sN\approx mg$

Answer (score 0):

Think about the extreme case where the track is covered in ice, and the car moves very slowly. It will slide towards the center. The minimum speed to avoid this is found by the balance of forces:

$$ N \sin \theta+\mu_s N \cos \theta = m \frac{v^2}{R} $$
  $$ N \cos \theta -\mu_s N \sin \theta = -m g $$

To be solved for the normal reaction force $N$ and minimum speed $v$.

The maximum speed is found by reversing the direction of friction by the balance of forces:

$$ N \sin \theta-\mu_s N \cos \theta = m \frac{v^2}{R} $$
  $$ N \cos \theta +\mu_s N \sin \theta = -m g $$

So in your relationship you just reverse the sign of $\mu_s$ to get the minimum speed.